# Cte blocks sql insert

Tags: mysql, sql

My code doesn't work if i have insertion in it.
Otherwise if i delete insertion part it would work fine (just selection)
Also deleting cte helps to avoid with insert but separately

```
WITH temp_cte as (select
     item_id AS item_id,
     item_name AS item_name,
     item_price AS item_price,
     date(created_dttm) AS valid_from_dt,
     LEAD(date(created_dttm), 1, '9999-12-31') 
     OVER (PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY date(created_dttm)) as next_price
     from item_prices)
      

     insert into dict_item_prices (item_id, item_name, item_price, valid_from_dt, valid_to_dt)
     
     
      SELECT item_id,
          item_name,
          item_price,
          valid_from_dt,
            (CASE  next_price
            WHEN '9999-12-31' THEN '9999-12-31'
            ELSE DATE_ADD(next_price,interval -1 day)
            END) as valid_to_dt
      from temp_cte

      select * from dict_item_prices;
```

even if I don't use my cte it's still fail

Comment: You have tagged both sql-serer and mysql. Those are two different products. Please remove one of those tags. (Base on your `DATE_ADD` usage, you appear to be using mysql..

Comment: Next, please use [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3aMmxpPT) or similar to create a minimal reproducible example. Define your table, insert sample data, and include your statement above to duplicate your stated problem. You may find that you have triggers or constraints (perhaps a unique constraint on item_id, next_price) that is key to reproducing your error. Data with next_date = '9999-12-31' might be key. Lastly, include the table definition, constraints, sample data, and a link to the minimal reproducible example page in your post above.

Comment: CTE is a part of SELECT, not a part of INSERT. So ``INSERT .. WITH .. SELECT ..``.

Answer (score 1):

The `WITH` clause is part if the select, so your query looks like

```
 insert into dict_item_prices (item_id, item_name, item_price, valid_from_dt, valid_to_dt)
WITH temp_cte as (select
     item_id AS item_id,
     item_name AS item_name,
     item_price AS item_price,
     date(created_dttm) AS valid_from_dt,
     LEAD(date(created_dttm), 1, '9999-12-31') 
     OVER (PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY date(created_dttm)) as next_price
     from item_prices)     
     
      SELECT item_id,
          item_name,
          item_price,
          valid_from_dt,
            (CASE  next_price
            WHEN '9999-12-31' THEN '9999-12-31'
            ELSE DATE_ADD(next_price,interval -1 day)
            END) as valid_to_dt
      from temp_cte;

  select * from dict_item_prices;
```